# about the method of cast in jdk

Tags: java

there is a method like this:

```
protected <T> T getBean(String beanId, Class<T> beanCls) {
return beanCls.cast(context.getBean(beanId));
}
```

`context.getBean(beanId)` can successfully return a pojo named "MobileUser," but what does that mean about `cast()`?what does it return?thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [java.lang.Class.cast()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Casts an object to the class or interface represented by this Class
>   object.

Read more about the usage of this method  here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_cast.htm

Comment: what you said  is the same as JDk,and i do some tests,now i know the meaning,thanks.